# Hide row in entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, entity-framework, orm

Have tried google etc to no avail. Is there a way to hide a row in entity framework based on a condition? IE
if row contains "this" then hide row?

Thanks
Chris

Comment: Hide what row? Can you be a little more clear

Comment: The table has three columns, Station Name, Location and Equipment Type. Old equipment that we no longer own, but still keep a record of having owned, is in a location called "Removed". I'd like to be able to hide any row where the location is equal to "Removed".

Comment: please update your question and give us some more details or it may be closed and/or downvoted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

```
var q = from e in dbContext.Equipment where !e.Location.Equals("Removed") select e;
```

Currently in EF6 are Global Query Filters not supported so you either have to specify the condition in every single query or use some third party solution like [EntityFramework.Filters](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/05/29/missing-ef-feature-workarounds-filters/).

See [this](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/945).